# Android P2P NFC

Tags: nfc, nfc-p2p

Im now working with an Android application based on NFC P2P technology. 
My question is:

Is it possible to create a P2P communication with external NFC IC(a not android powered device), to communicate with a MCU??

Thanks allready

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Arduino + [NFC shiled](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/nfc-shield-v20-p-1370.html?cPath=19_24) to communicate with android using p2p protocol. NFC shield uses PN532 chip(not a mcu). There is a library --- https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532 for you.